# Changing row color on click - ASP.NET and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview, background-color

Using the `e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'");` I am able to highlight a selection with a mouseclick in an ASP.NET GridView.

This works, however, each row that is clicked has it's background colour changed, and if I click on another row, the previously clicked row remains highlighted.

Is there any way on how to fix this, i.e. reset all other rows and highlight only currently selected?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume it will looks like

then

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "colorchange");
```

and your javascript code will looks like

```
 $('.colorchange').click(function()
    {
    $('.colorchange').backgroundColor="";
    $(this).backgroundColor="your color name";

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set AutoGenerateSelectButton property to true then its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add class **clicked** and toggle it on click event:
**No JQuery**:
Server side:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Click(this)");
```

Client side:

```
Click = function(el) {
    var clicked = document.querySelectorAll(".clicked");
    for (var i = 0, length = clicked.length; i < length; i++) {
        removeClass(clicked[i], "clicked");
    }

    el.className = el.className + "clicked";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cd2Q9/11/

**JQuery**:
Server side:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "clickable");
```

Client side:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aB5cm/